# update Object inside array of Object with mongoose

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I'm trying to update and object inside array in MongoDB.
my model is:

```
let userSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  userName: {
    type: String
  },
  password: {
    type: String
  },
  history: []

});
```

And inside history each element is from the next type:
`id`, `array`(named ing_array) and `boolean` field called favorite.

I'm trying to update the `favorite` field with mongoose with the userName and the id.

I tried to do this query and I didn't succed.
Could some one tell me whats worng?
[object photo]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/2mYpP.png

```
User.findOneAndUpdate(
  { "userName": user_name, "history.id": id },
  { "$set": { "history.$.favorite": true }}
);
```

Answer (score 3):

You have to use [`arrayFilters`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/positional-filtered/) in this way:

```
db.collection.update({
  "userName": "uname",
  "history.id": 1
},
{
  "$set": {
    "history.$[element].favorite": false
  }
},
{
  "arrayFilters": [
    {
      "element.id": 1
    }
  ]
})
```

Note that `update` query has the format: `update(query, update, options)` (Check the [docs](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.update/)).

When you do `{ "userName": user_name, "history.id": id }` you are telling mongo "Give me all documents where `userName` is `user_name` and array `history` has an `id` with value `id`. This return all `history` array because it belows to the document.

To update an specific object into the array is neccessary to use `arrayFilters` to tell mongo which object do you want to update. In this case the object where `id` is equal to `1`. You can use as you want to match wit your requirements.

Example [here](https://mongoplayground.net/p/s-GB6DnxoR2)

Comment: first of all thank you, i need to put the name of the mongoose model instead the db.collection right? if i med let User= mongoose.mode('User,...) so i need to do User.update?

Comment: Yes! You have to use your mongoose model `User.updateOne(/*the query*/)`.

Comment: its not working for me..i see that in the example its working.. do you can suggest what is the problem?

Comment: What's the problem? Is not updating the field? Check if first object (query object) is finding some document using `yourModel.find({ "userName": user_name, "history.id": id })`. If this works the query should works. Also note that where I've used `"element.id": 1` you have to use `"element.id": id`

Comment: i think that the problem is in the history array. 
i dont think that i can do history.id becuse history is an array so i think this is the problem.. do you have any clue?

Comment: Dot notation is used with arrays too. Check the [documentation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/document/#arrays) and check [this example](https://mongoplayground.net/p/djIeGt-BWqw)