# change fields of object inside array in mongoose

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query

my application tracking student enrollment to different courses.

the schema is:

```
const userSchema = new mongoose.Schema({

    username: String,
    password: Number,
    enrollment: []

})
```

and the enrollment array looks like this:

```
[{courseName: somename, courseTime:sometime},{courseName: somename2, courseTime:sometime2}]
```

the student can supply information whether he was attend at specific date on the course meeting or not.

so the thing I want to do is:

a) find the specific student
b) find the the specific course of this student
c) add to the object that contains this course additional object that contain date field and yes/no field.

so i wont it looks something  like this:

```
[{courseName: somename, courseTime:sometime, newObject:{date:someDate, attendance:true}},{courseName: somename2, courseTime:sometime2,newObject:{date:someDate2, attendance:false}}]
```

I found similar questions in topics like this:
[update Object inside array of Object with mongoose](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68817676/update-object-inside-array-of-object-with-mongoose)
or
[update Object inside array of Object with mongoose](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68817676/update-object-inside-array-of-object-with-mongoose)

and its not seems like a very hard task, but the problem is that I probably missing some simple syntax rules, because when I type this code into VScode I see picture like this:

[image: error]

any help would be much appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Here's one way to `update` `"enrollment"` and add `"newObject"`.

```js
db.collection.update({
  "username": "john1234" // from req.body.username
},
{
  "$set": {
    "enrollment.$[course].newObject": {
      // from req.body.xxx
      "date": ISODate("2022-12-01T09:00:00Z"),
      "attendance": true
    }
  }
},
{
  "arrayFilters": [
    { // from req.body.courseName
      "course.courseName": "NIE-SW101"
    }
  ]
})
```

Example output:

```json
[
  {
    "_id": ObjectId("5a934e000102030405000000"),
    "enrollment": [
      {
        "courseName": "NIE-SW101",
        "courseTime": ISODate("2022-12-01T09:00:00Z"),
        "newObject": {
          "attendance": true,
          "date": ISODate("2022-12-01T09:00:00Z")
        }
      },
      {
        "courseName": "NIE-HI101",
        "courseTime": ISODate("2022-12-05T15:00:00Z")
      }
    ],
    "password": 1234,
    "username": "john1234"
  }
]
```

Try it on [mongoplayground.net](https://mongoplayground.net/p/-gbrAl4vZHe).